# Client.UploadString not allowing "&"

Tags: c#

When sending the string:

```
client.UploadString(
    string.Format(SendToServiceURL 
        + "api/SendCardRequest?merchantId={0}&productCode={1}&password={2}",
        MerchantId, 
        ProductCode, 
        Password),
    "POST");
```

The password I'm testing is `<&>`

It seems to delete everything after the ampersand.

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: You should encode your URL.

Comment: By _Client_ did you mean `WebClient`, right?

Comment: Hi apologies I had a colleague post this as I was not at a pc and he did leave out relevant info. Client is a WebClient yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance you need to URL encode the ampersand as it's used to separate out parameters.

For example:

```
string.Format(
    SendToServiceURL + "api/SendCardRequest?merchantId={0}&productCode{1}&password={2}",
    MerchantId,
    ProductCode,
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Password) // URL encode password
)
```

You can use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.

You might also want to consider encoding the other values as well unless you can guarantee that they won't collide with any URL specific characters.

Comment: Should probably do the same with `ProductCode` (and `MerchantId` if it's not an integer type)

Comment: Should it encode everything after `?` instead? Just in case.

Comment: @VitorCanova Yes and no. If you can guarantee the values aren't going to be an issue I don't see the point. But too little information to make that call here really.

Comment: Hi apologies I had a colleague post this as I was not at a pc and he did leave out relevant info. The`MerchantId` is always of a integer type and so should be grand and `productCode` is a string that will never contain any complex characters so both of them should be handled ok. Ill try and implement this now. Thanks very much!